# Reverse the direction of the warning message of Dialog box

Tags: css, dialog, modal-dialog, office-js

We develop an Excel add-in. To set the minimise wide of the add-in. We have the following CSS setting

```
body {
  min-width: 300px; /* Your desired minimum width */
  direction: rtl; /* Right-to-Left direction to make content stick to the right */
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Hide horizontal overflow */
}

.addin-component {
  direction: ltr
}
```

And we apply `addin-component` to the entire add-in. As a result, when the taskpane is too narrow, there is no scrollbar and users can only see a part of the add-in page. This behavior is what we wanted.

It works well except for the dialog box launched by `Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync`. When we launch a popup by `Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync`, normally there is a warning `xxxx wants to display a new window.` Because of `direction: rtl`, the warning is displayed right-to-left now.

Does anyone know how we could reverse the direction for this warning message?